No me funciona la Invocación de la vista register.blade.php desde una opción del menu
Soy nuevo en el uso de Laravel Jetstream y estoy queriendo desarrollar una aplicación. Lo que intento hacer es reutilizar la vista register.blade.php para que el administrador de la aplicación pueda realizar el alta de nuevos usuarios. Para ello agregué como opción del menú la llamada a la vista register de esta forma:
   <x-nav-link href="{{ route('register') }}" >
         {{ __('Alta Usuario') }}
   </x-nav-link>

Pero cuando lo hago click sobre la opción del menú no redirige a la vista register, se queda en la pantalla de Dashboard.
¿Cómo debería hacer la invocación?
